# ssh in mobaXterm can't resolve the IP address

Tags: ssh, mobaxterm

I have problem with name resolving in mobaXterm, if I want to use ssh. Doesn't matter if I have IP address in hosts, or I use a domain name. Command dig, or ping can resolve IP address, but ssh not. Do maybe somebody know, what is a problem here?

Thank you
[image]

Comment: I have integrated the image in your question.

Comment: By chance, try `google.com.` - note the ending extra dot.

Comment: What happens when NOT in MobaXterm?